# Using Queue for mailing but laravel 5.4 does not seem to respond

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using queues for the first time and I don't seem to get it to work and laravel does not seem to throw any errors.

I am trying to queue mail on user registration, that is user should be redirected to dashboard immediately and the email should be queued. How do I know if queue is not working? on clicking register I have to wait for 8 seconds before I see dashboard, I get the email on registration but queue seems to fail.

I dont see any queue jobs on mysql jobs table at the time of registration.

## Below are my settings:

## jobs and jobs-failed table created using below command:

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan queue:failed-table
php artisan migrate
```

## .env

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=dummy@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="App name"
```

## RegisterController create() function

at the end of create function just before `return $user;`

```
dispatch(new NewRegisteredUser($user));
```

## jobs file: NewRegisteredUser

```laravel
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\RegisteredUserWelcome;

class NewRegisteredUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new RegisteredUserWelcome($this->user);
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->queue($email);
    }
}
```

## Mail file: RegisteredUserWelcome

```laravel
namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RegisteredUserWelcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.registered')
            ->with([
                        'firstname' => $this->user->firstname,
                        'lastname' => $this->user->lastname,
                    ]);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? I dont get error and mail is sent but no queue jobs observed in mysql and long wait time on registration.

I am also confused how this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#queueing-mail fits with this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues Why do we need queues separately when we already have queuing in mail?

What should I use and how? All I need to do is reduce the wait-time of users and send mails behind the scene. Also, I am sending multiple emails in some cases. I guess this would help if I queue the jobs of multiple emails.

Comment: did you run `php artisan queue:listen` ?

Comment: @Rodrane I tried both one by one php artisan queue:work and listen I just think it might be working now because the delay was of 3 seconds instead of 8 seconds. 3 seconds is maybe new user created and I have a very large chunk of code on the controller. But I am not sure how to make sure if queue really works. I commented the code and mail was not sent meaning the Queue jobs and Mail file is being executed.

Comment: you can check from database not exactly sure which but there are tables about failed jobs queued jobs.

Comment: @Rodrane both are empty. if I dont run php artisan queue:listen or work I expect to see the table filled with a job but that is not happening. both jobs table and failed-jobs are empty :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used markdown as the mail template

I got Queues to work and the output is seen in `php artisan queue:listen`.

The issue was .env file was not clear cached. `php artisan config:clear` made it to work. Queues can be made much more efficient by simply delaying the job.

I delayed the job by 60 seconds (1 minute) and things work really well.

I will post all the code and files I had to create to make it work.

setting .env file

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=dummy@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls or ssl"  (double quotes not required)
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="email address to be shown to email receiver" (double quotes not required)
MAIL_FROM_NAME="App Name" (double quotes not required only if you have blank space between the name)
```

This line of code makes sure new values in .env file is taken into consideration

```
php artisan config:clear
```

In my Controller file

```
use Mail;
use App\Jobs\NewprofileCreated;
use App\Mail\ProfileCreated;
```

Controller Code

```
dispatch((new NewprofileCreated($user))->delay(60));
```

Two files created using below command

```
php artisan make:job NewprofileCreated
php artisan make:mail ProfileCreated
```

NewprofileCreated Job file

```laravel
use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\ProfileCreated;

class NewprofileCreated implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
         $email = new ProfileCreated($this->user);
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->queue($email);
    }
}
```

ProfileCreated Mail file

```laravel
class ProfileCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.profile_created');
    }
}
```

profile_created markdown template (folder: view/emails/profile_created)

```
@component('mail::message')

<h1>Your new profile is created</h1>

You have received this email because your profile was created for {{ config('app.name') }}


Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Great! You wrote it so well!